# Hard coded image size vs dynamic set of image size for a browser game framework?

Tags: javascript, image, assets

I would like to know what are the cons and the pros of having a framework where (A) you set the image like this:

```
var image = new Image("path", width, height);
```

and the width and height is hardcoded.

My second idea was (B) to set the width and height of the image after it was loaded. In this case the image is only requested (to the server) when has a render request. After the image is loaded it sets the width/height based on it's metadata. like this:

```
var image = new Image("path");

    // somewhere into the renderer after the image has been loaded
    image.setWidth(width);
    image.setHeight(height);
```

Answer (score 0):

Well as far as page weight goes, you will be better able to use responsive images responsibly with the former. Imagine The same page being viewed on a 27 inch Monitor and on an iPhone.

You could detect the screen size and load an image of appropriate size so that you don't load a 600kb hero image for a 320px wide iPhone. You could load the 15kb baby brother of that image instead.

In your second example, you would already have loaded the image by the time you figure out the size, so you lose the chance to save bandwidth by loading a smaller version of the image.

Also, depending on where this function is in the source order, you're probably going to cause a redraw if you resize the image after load, which is slow and kinda lame.

Comment: Thanks for the insight, I didn't even think about the part of loading resources based on their size. But thinking better the width and height of the image will be kind of harcoded. I could use a scale factor and then when I load the image it will be based on the current scale * size, so it will load the right image for the right scale (therefore the right screen size)

Comment: are you manipulating the DOM with this, or are you doing this before the image is displayed?

Comment: well, it's a bit more complicated: the renderer takes the nodes to render and then renders them. The default (stupid-low performance) renderer renders everything to the canvas. The smart one will notice the times has moved and the time taken to render and will choose between rendering it into the canvas and putting the image in a dom element.